# Mongodb aggregation changes not being persisted in go

Tags: mongodb, go, aggregation

I'm running an aggregation to remove stale documents but the changes don't actually affect the database. The query ignores already expired documents, so the number of results should change after each query runs, but it doesn't.

```golang
func CheckShipmentExpiryDates(c *mongo.Client) (int, error) {
    numberOfExpiredShipments := 0
    coll := c.Database(os.Getenv("DATABASE")).Collection("shipments")
    update := bson.M{"$set": bson.M{"status": "EXPIRED", "updated_at": time.Now()}}
    pipeline := []bson.M{
        {"$lookup": bson.M{
            "from": "shipment_quotes",
            "let":  bson.M{"shipmentID": "$_id"},
            "pipeline": []bson.M{
                {"$match": bson.M{"$expr": bson.M{"$and": []bson.M{{"$eq": []string{"$shipment_id", "$$shipmentID"}}, {"$eq": []string{"$status", "WON"}}}}}},
            },
            "as": "quotes",
        }},
        {"$match": bson.M{"expiration_date": bson.M{"$exists": true}}},
        {"$match": bson.M{"$expr": bson.M{"$and": []bson.M{
            {"$ne": []string{"$status", "EXPIRED"}},
            {"$lt": []interface{}{"$expiration_date", time.Now()}},
            {"$eq": []interface{}{bson.M{"$size": "$quotes"}, 0}},
            {"expiration_date": bson.M{"$type": 9}},
        }}}},
        update,
    }

    err := c.UseSession(context.TODO(), func(sessionContext mongo.SessionContext) error {
        if err := sessionContext.StartTransaction(); err != nil {
            return err
        }
        cursor, err := coll.Aggregate(sessionContext, pipeline)
        if err != nil {
            _ = sessionContext.AbortTransaction(sessionContext)
            return err
        }

        var shipments []bson.M
        if err := cursor.All(sessionContext, &shipments); err != nil {
            _ = sessionContext.AbortTransaction(sessionContext)
            return err
        }

        fmt.Println("~First shipment's status", shipments[0]["shipment_unique_number"], shipments[0]["status"])

        numberOfExpiredShipments = len(shipments)

        fmt.Println(sessionContext.CommitTransaction(sessionContext))
        return nil
    })

    return numberOfExpiredShipments, err
}
```

As you can see, I'm logging the first result and checking it against the database in real time, using compass, but the changes aren't actually being persisted. The query runs over and over again, returning the same number of expired shipments.

```golang
mc, mongoErr := connection.MongoInit()
    if mongoErr != nil {
        panic(mongoErr)
    }
    utils.InitDB(mc)
    defer func() {
        if err := mc.Disconnect(context.TODO()); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }()

    n := connection.NewNotificationCenter()
    sseInit(mc, googleApi, n)
    graphSchema, err := schema.InjectSchema(mutationInit(mc, googleApi), queryInit(mc, googleApi))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    restApiUseCase := mutationsRestApiInit(mc, googleApi)
    connection.InjectGraphqlHandler(graphSchema, n, restApiUseCase)

    initIncrementStartdate(mc)
    initShipmentExpiredCron(mc)
```

```golang
func initShipmentExpiredCron(mg *mongo.Client) {
    c := cron.New()
    c.AddFunc("*/5 * * * *", func() {
        expiredShipments, err := utils.CheckShipmentExpiryDates(mg)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("CRON ERROR: An error occured while trying to check the expiry date for each shipment")
            log.Println(err)
        } else {
            // Print how many shipments are expired
            log.Println("CRON SUCCESS: The following number of shipments have expired: ", expiredShipments)
        }
    })
    c.Start()
}
```

I really don't understand what's wrong with it.

Comment: I think the problem might be that $set doesn't work in aggregations? There are dozens of other places in the project where $set seems to be used in aggregations and work. We picked up this project in a really sorry state, so it could be that I'm misunderstanding. 

The problem is I can't use $lookup in updateMany, only in aggregations.

Comment: I don't know `go` so I can't follow all the code, but the aggregation pipeline,as is, won't modify the document/collection/database - it's just a query.  You might consider appending [`"$merge"`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/) to your pipeline to actually make a modification.  I'm not sure which `"$merge"` options you may want to use, if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rickhg12hs was right, I needed to also use `$merge`. Oddly, this makes the aggregation not return anything, so now I don't know the number of shipments that have expired, but that was not really necessary. This is the pipeline at the end

```golang
pipeline := []bson.M{{
  "$lookup": bson.M{
    "from": "shipment_quotes",
    "let": bson.M{
      "shipmentID": "$_id"
    },
    "pipeline": []bson.M{{
      "$match": bson.M{
        "$expr": bson.M{
          "$and": []bson.M{{
            "$eq": []string{
              "$shipment_id", "$$shipmentID"
            }}, {
              "$eq": []string{
                "$status", "WON"
              }
            }
          }}
        }
      },
    },
    "as": "quotes",
  }}, {
    "$match": bson.M{
      "expiration_date": bson.M{
        "$exists": true
      }
    }
  }, {
    "$match": bson.M{
      "$expr": bson.M{
        "$and": []bson.M{{
          "$ne": []string{
            "$status", "EXPIRED"
          }
        }, {
          "$lt": []interface{}{
            "$expiration_date", time.Now()
          }
        }, {
          "$eq": []interface{}{
            bson.M{
              "$size": "$quotes"
            }, 0
          }
        }, {
          "expiration_date": bson.M{
            "$type": 9
          }
        },
      }
    }
  }},
  update,
  {
    "$merge": bson.M{
      "into": "shipments",
      "on": "_id"
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: The aggregation query with `$merge` (also, `$out`) as the last stage returns an _empty cursor_ - hence, no return value.